# Scope and usefulness of questions about computer operating systems and computer hardwares

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

I am not much active user here but I once (more than a year ago) asked [a question on Computer Operating system](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/52192/23415) which was well received by this community. Recently I posted [another one](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/60134/23415) and am thinking of creating tag for computer operating system but not sure, so I asked it to moderator who is available in chat. He [suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54853385#54853385) me to post a question on Meta.

So, I am posting this question to cover the computer operating system and computer hardwares in general. Would it be useful to create a tag dedicated to operating systems? Or would it be more useful to post this type of questions on [Retrocomputing.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) as suggested in [comments](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/60134/when-was-the-term-multics-operating-system-coined-and-by-whom#comment183035_60134)?

Comment: As for numbers, there are currently 21 questions on this site tagged [tag:computers], including the two linked above. IMHO, of those 21, 3 would be candidates for an Operating System tag: the two linked above and one more that is currently closed.

Comment: Also, a lot of the more history oriented computing questions would also be on topic on [History of Science and Math](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions), although its still a beta site.

Comment: I have just looked at [the scope of Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and found that computing history questions are on-topic! :) I have just flagged to migrate my recent question.

Comment: Well, I'd like to reiterate that its not *off*-topic here. However, that's a site that's likely to get more good answers for computing history questions that are still in living memory.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's not off-topic here.